# Does Feathers Authentication also require app internal service calls to be authenticated (and how to get around)?

Tags: express, passport.js, feathersjs

I'm building a FeathersJS service behind an authentication very similar to the messages service that is part of the FeathersJS demo chat app: https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-chat/

Additionally, I'd like to define an event listener that should store the messages it receives to the app's messages service and call all necessary hooks to notify the client application.

Here's my current approach:

```
module.exports = function () {
  const app = this;
  const Model = createModel(app);
  const paginate = app.get('paginate');

  const options = {
    name: 'messages',
    Model,
    paginate
  };

  app.use('/messages', createService(options));

  const service = app.service('messages');
  service.hooks(hooks);

  const sender = new MyExternalMessageSender();
  sender.on('message', (msg) => {
    service.create(msg, {user: {_id: 0}}).then(result => console.log(result));
  });

  if (service.filter) {
    service.filter(filters);
  }
};
```

This sometimes works fine and sometimes it randomly results in an error as soon as `MyExternalMessageSender` is notified and tries to call the message service's `create` method.

```
NotAuthenticated: No auth token
 at Error.NotAuthenticated (projects\feathers-chat\node_modules\feathers-errors\lib\index.js:100:17)
 at projects\feathers-chat\node_modules\feathers-authentication\lib\hooks\authenticate.js:102:31
```

How can I store messages the correct way without my application itself needing to use a JWT?

Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what `MyExternalMessageSender` does but authentication *is* skipped by default in internal service calls. If it is an internal service call is determined by `params.provider` being set. So if you pass `hook.params` from an external call (where `provider` is normally set to `rest` or `socketio`) to subsequent service calls authentication will run (since it thinks it is an external call).

This can be avoided by removing the `provider` property before passing the original parameters e.g. with [Lodash _.omit](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#omit):

```
myservice.find(_.omit(params, 'provider'))
```

Comment: Thanks, this gives much insight in how the hooks work. Just think of `MyExternalMessageSender` as an async EventListener, that will sometimes create new messages. The problem persists: When I start up the app, sometimes everything works fine and sometimes incoming messages aren't stored at app level and will show the NotAuthenticated-Error above. Restarting the app sometimes helps and sometimes not. Any ideas how to approach the error cause? What could lead to the authentication being fired although it shouldn't?